# How to setup Azure App Service to run on .Net Core through Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I've set-up an App Service using the following ARM template snippet:

```
{
  "name": "[variables('webBackEnd')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName')))]": "Resource",
    "displayName": "BackendWebApp"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('webBackEnd')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
  }
},
```

This will deploy an App Service. However, by default, it will be setup to use the .Net Framework. Below is a view from my Azure Portal:

[image: App Service configured to run .Net Framework]

In order to run my ASP.Net Core-based web server, I have to manually switch the Stack Settings from ".Net" to ".Net Core". It's a trivial thing to do, but I'd much rather configure it correctly through the ARM template. I searched [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2016-08-01/sites/config) but was unable to find the correct property. How does one go about to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

here's how an example web app looks when created from the portal:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
    "name": "[parameters('name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": [],
            "metadata": [
                {
                    "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                    "value": "[parameters('currentStack')]"
                }
            ]
        },
        // redacted some values
    }
},
```

and the current stack value is `dotnetcore`

Comment: Very interesting. When I create an App Service in the Portal, the runtime will be preset to ".Net Core". But I don't see any difference in the exported ARM template. Moreover, the "metadata" property which seems to control the stack setting is not documented in [Microsoft.Web sites template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-11-01/sites)

Comment: template reference is garbage, unfortunately

Comment: I verified that your solution works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: I confirm that this configuration works to set the Web App stack to .NET Core. Although, it seems the Web App needs to be "Restarted" for the .NET Core support to fully work after initial deployment. Seems to be a bug with this currently...

Comment: Given that the reference is garbage, and that the portal is not generating the CURRENT_STACK metadata thing, how on earth did you find out?

Comment: ugh, this was long time ago, I'm not sure exactly, I think I created an App Service using the portal and set it to use dotnetcore and examined the template that the portal used to create the webapp with those settings. ps. I'd also appreciate an upvote ;) @EsbenBach

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have to ask this: As Esben Back said the exported template does NOT show metadata how did you find out then? What do you mean by "examined the template"?

Comment: sorry, I answer hundreds of questions here, I dont really remember. i guess what it says. start creating the webapp and look at the template that gets used before you hit create? @AlexanderSchmidt

Comment: See this question for a comment about discovering this during creation 
 in portal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59140969/arm-template-azure-web-app-how-do-you-specify-stack-settings-net-net-core

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I began my own investigation and finished with this code, which works in my case.

```
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
"apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
"name": "[parameters('site_name')]",
"location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
.........................................

"resources": [
 {
    "name": "metadata",
    "type": "config",
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('site_name'))]"
    ],
    "tags": {
    },
    "properties": {
        "CURRENT_STACK": "dotnetcore"
    }
 }
]
```