# ARM template Azure Web App - How do you specify Stack Settings (.NET, .NET Core,...)?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-webapps

In ARM template for Azure Web App, how do you specify the stack settings for the app (.NET, .NET Core, PHP, ...)? I cannot see any field for it.

Thank you

Comment: Hi! Would you explain the problem please? Maybe could you paste code that you have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you create azure webapp on portal, choose `Running stack` as `.Net Core 3.0(Current)`.

Then click `Review+Create` > `Download a template for automation`. You will see the ARM template which contain `metadata` attribute and the current stack value is `dotnetcore`.

[image]

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
    "name": "[parameters('name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": [],
            "metadata": [
                {
                    "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                    "value": "[parameters('currentStack')]"
                }
            ]
        },
        // redacted some values
    }
}
```

Comment: for .Net Core: `"CURRENT_STACK": { "value": "dotnetcore" }`

Comment: As a small note: This solution does only work for NEW WebApps... if you want to CHANGE an existing WebApp from .NEt to .NEtCore you also must clear "netFrameworkVersion". Otherwise the stack is not changed.

Comment: Observation: for .NET 6, the ARM template generated by Azure Portal has `CURRENT_STACK=dotnet`, and not `CURRENT_STACK=dotnetcore` as in .NET Core 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Joey's answer, the value for CURRENT_STACK for .NET Core would be `dotnetcore`.

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "<name>",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "app",
            "properties": {
                "enabled": true,
                "siteConfig": {
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                            "value": "dotnetcore"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As a small note: This proposed solution does only work for NEW WebApps... if you want to CHANGE an existing WebApp from .Net4.x to .NetCore you also must clear "netFrameworkVersion". Otherwise the stack is not changed.

So correct would be:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
    "name": "[parameters('name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": [],
            "netFrameworkVersion": "",
            "metadata": [
                {
                    "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                    "value": "dotnetcore"
                }
            ]
        },
        // redacted some values
    }
}
```