# Does Azure portal using undocumented ARM features to deploy App Services?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I'm looking at template generated for adding Web App which is generated by Azure portal. I chose .NET core as runtime and it's passed to `metadata` field in generated ARM template below with a value of `dotnetcore`. The end result is resource created in Azure with all the stuff you expect from web app. I don't see this field being documented and or explanation how it's being used. Is it some internal know-how or how this process works?

```
 "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "dependsOn": [],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "ANCM_ADDITIONAL_ERROR_PAGE_LINK",
                            "value": "[parameters('errorLink')]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                            "value": "[parameters('currentStack')]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "phpVersion": "[parameters('phpVersion')]",
                    "alwaysOn": "[parameters('alwaysOn')]"
                },
                "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": true
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I  don't see it on their documentation page here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites

but i did find it mentioned, and also the technique to find other properties as you have found, on their official github here
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/43963

Comment: As far as I know, this is undocumented. It can be discovered through Azure Portal, though. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59140969/2157640